# Spring: Requiring trailing slash after context path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 1.3 application with server.contextPath=/ts in development mode.

From a browser, I can access it at either http://localhost:8888/ts or http://localhost:8888/ts/

However from the browser's perspective that's very different when accessing resources using relative paths. Without the trailing slash, all javascript AJAX calls strip the "ts" from the requested path.

In production this does not occur as the front-end ensures the trailing slash.

I'm looking for a solution that would redirect the browser from "/ts" to "/ts/" so that relative paths are predictable. I've tried various strategies (setUseTrailingSlashMatch=false, redirects) but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty normal, and you can even test that on Java by testing `java.net.URL`. In essence, you have these combinations:

`http://foo.com/example/bar/ + baz -> http://foo.com/example/bar/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar/ + ./baz -> http://foo.com/example/bar/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar/ + ../baz -> http://foo.com/example/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar/ + /baz -> http://foo.com/baz`

BUT!

`http://foo.com/example/bar + baz -> http://foo.com/example/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar + ./baz -> http://foo.com/example/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar + ../baz -> http://foo.com/baz
http://foo.com/example/bar + /baz -> http://foo.com/baz`

I would suggest just go to the browser's history and delete the unslashed version, and you will not get any more autocomplete suggestions. If that doesn't do what you want, add a servlet filter that will redirect to the proper page when the final slash is missing.

Comment: This is not about autocomplete in the browser. It's about Spring that invokes the application even without the trailing slash. When I add a redirect rule from /ts to /ts/, that creates a redirect loop because those are the same for Spring. I thought using setUseTrailingSlashMatch=false would help but it does not.

Comment: Do not set the redirect rule on spring; add a servlet filter that does it, it should have the original path available.